# Unusual "half border" situation with tmux

Tags: terminal, colors, tmux, border

My tmux occasionally gets into a weird state where half the border (regardless of orientation, or (tmux) window focus) is bolded, highlighted?

See the screenshot below:

[image: screen shot of tmux with half the window border bolded]

Weirdly, even after completely killing tmux I can recover from this state, but then half the border is colored, see the second screenshot:

[image: screen shot of tmux with half the border highlighte]

In the second screenshot, although subtle half the border is colored white, the other half green.

*Note:* The orange/green difference is irrelevant here, I tried a "fix" for weird borders which forced them to orange, and that affected the screenshot I made.

I don't believe I have any unusual configuration:

```
new-session -n $HOST
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tpm'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible'
set -g @plugin 'nhdaly/tmux-scroll-copy-mode'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-yank'
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
set-window-option -g allow-rename off
set-window-option -g automatic-rename off
set-option -g mouse on
set -g @shell_mode 'vi'
set -g @yank_selection 'clipboard'
set -g @yank_selection_mouse 'clipboard'
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

Is this a mis-feature, why is only half colored/bolded, why does the bolding only happen sometimes, and why is it not affected by zooming or mouse clicking in or around the windows?

The fact that I cannot reliably reproduce, nor dismiss this once it happens leads me to assume this is a bug but I'm just not sure.

tmux version is 2.9x, terminal is alacritty 0.4.0, operating system is Feroda, and my `$TERM` variable seems to be `screen`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal.

The active pane is embraced in a colored frame. When there are exactly two panes, just coloring the *whole* dividing line would say nothing about which pane is active. For this reason `tmux` applies the color to *one half* of the line. If you make the other pane active, the coloring will change. This way you can tell which pane is active.

"Bold" line behaves in the same manner, only it indicates the marked pane (default keystrokes to mark/unmark: <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> or RMB).

In your first screenshot the left pane is marked but the right one is active. In your second screenshot there is no marked pane and the bottom pane is active.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, what a terrible default from tmux, this looks broken, and the "marking" of panes seems completely silly. The "half line" coloring seems arbitrary and completely unintuitive. I have always relied on seeing my cursor in the active window and not in the inactive ones. Thanks so much. Now to disable all this.

Comment: Many applications turn the cursor off completely. We tried a few ways of marking and this is the best.

Comment: Good point about some apps being cursorless. Now I know that pane marking is a feature, and the difference between half-coloring the border when there are only two splits, the feature makes sense, it's just super undiscoverable, and unintuitive, but I appreciate the difficulty of finding a ubiquitous solution.