# Transpose panes in tmux

Tags: tmux

I have 6 panes open in a tmux window.

<kbd>Prefix</kbd>`:select-layout tiled` arranges them as such:

```
+---------+---------+
|    1    |    2    |
+---------+---------+
|    3    |    4    |
+---------+---------+
|    5    |    6    |
+---------+---------+
```

That's nice, but my monitor is wide and short, and for the processes I'm running it's a huge waste of horizontal space.

I'd much rather arrange them as such:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  |  2  |  3  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  4  |  5  |  6  |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Assuming that the numeric ordering of the panes themselves doesn't matter, and crucially without stopping any of my running processes, how can I switch from the first layout to the second?

Comment: I recreated the upper layout. If I move the line between 3 and 4, other lines are unaffected. If I move the line between 1 and 3, it takes the line between 2 and 4 with it; you can call them a single long horizontal line. This raises a question: in the lower layout, do you want the horizontal or vertical lines to be "screen long"? Or maybe you don't care?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Me personally, I don't care - I have no plans on disturbing this balanced layout. I suppose having the vertical lines be "screen long" would be slightly preferable, if only so that I could have a full vertical panel show my `top` in the case that I'm able to drop a pane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [tmuxlayout](https://metacpan.org/pod/tmuxlayout) which is a perl script where you would just run, in another window, `tmuxlayout 123 456` and it would send the appropriate commands to the running tmux.

It could be a bit hard to install as it may not be in a repository for your distribution.

---

If you want to install `tmuxlayout` locally, without being root or messing up your `/usr/lib` and so on, you can do so after installing the `cpan` command, which should be in your repository.

You can then run `cpan` interactively as shown below with only 3 lines of input. It will create only 2 directories in your `$HOME`: `perl5/` and `.cpan`.

In the following I've removed the copious output, so simply press return when asked to configure automatically `yes`, press return when asked to choose `local::lib`, then type the command `install Term::Tmux::Layout`.

```
$ cpan
Would you like to configure as much as possible automatically? [yes] 
What approach do you want?  (Choose 'local::lib', 'sudo' or 'manual')
 [local::lib] 
cpan[1]> install Term::Tmux::Layout
```

If it said the install was OK, at the next prompt type control-D to exit, and note the values it asks you to set:

```
cpan[2]> ^D
*** Remember to add these environment variables to your shell config
and restart your shell before running cpan again ***
PATH="/home/meuh/perl5/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}"; export PATH;
PERL5LIB="/home/meuh/perl5/lib/perl5${PERL5LIB:+:${PERL5LIB}}"; export PERL5LIB;
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="/home/meuh/perl5${PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT:+:${PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT}}"; export PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT;
PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base \"/home/meuh/perl5\""; export PERL_MB_OPT;
PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/home/meuh/perl5"; export PERL_MM_OPT;
```

Create a small shell script with the above 5 lines, and add at the end

```
tmuxlayout 123 456
```

and run the script.

Comment: Seems like the perfect solution in theory - sadly I have no idea how to install this, especially without root. perl is a whole new world to me and it's not a world I can just justify spending much time exploring, sorry! But thank you for your answer!

Comment: I've added the info on how to use `cpan` to install the command in your home directory.

Comment: Thank you!! I did manage to get to the `install Term::Tmux::Layout` stage but was met with permission errors - I must have messed up the initial config because I then ran `o conf init` to redo it and the second install worked fine. This solution is disgustingly overcomplicated but it does work and you have my eternal gratitude.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote the below script to easily place panes in a grid. It uses a function from [Sleep_Walker's blog](http://sleepwalker-hnd.blogspot.com/2016/07/tmux-layout-checksum.html). It's unclear to me what the licence is. To be on the safe side I removed the function from my code and posted it separately as a proper citation.

**You need to compose the full script by pasting the function into the script.**

```
#!/bin/bash

# number of rows
m="$2"
# number of columns
n="$1"

target="${3:-$TMUX_PANE}"
set -- $(tmux list-panes -t "$target" -F '#{pane_id}')

n="${n:-$(($#/m))}"
m="${m:-$(($#/n))}"

if [ "$#" -ne "$((m*n))" ]; then
    printf '%s: panes needed for %sx%s layout: %s; panes detected: %s. Aborting.\n' "$0" "$n" "$m" "$((m*n))" "$#" >&2
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$m" -eq 1 ]; then
   layout=even-horizontal
elif [ "$n" -eq 1 ]; then
   layout=even-vertical
else

# ---------- IMPORTANT ----------
# Visit http://sleepwalker-hnd.blogspot.com/2016/07/tmux-layout-checksum.html
# and paste tmux_layout_checksum function here.

   create_row() {
      row="${n}x1,0,${1}{"
      shift
      for j in $(seq 0 "$((n-1))"); do
         row="${row}1x1,${j},0,${1#%},"
         shift
      done
      row="${row%,}},"
   }

   layout="${n}x${m},0,0["
   for i in $(seq 0 "$((m-1))"); do
      create_row "$i" "$@"
      shift "$n"
      layout="${layout}${row}"
   done
   layout="${layout%,}]"
   layout="$(tmux_layout_checksum "$layout"),${layout}"

fi

tmux select-layout -t "$target" "$layout"
```

The mentioned function:

> ```
> tmux_layout_checksum() {
>     local layout="$1"
>     local csum=0
>     local i
>     for i in $(seq 0 $((${#layout} - 1))); do
>         let csum=$(((csum >> 1) + ((csum & 1) << 15)))
>         let csum=$((csum + $(LC_CTYPE=C printf '%d' "'${layout:$i:1}")))
>     done
>     printf '%x' "$((csum & 0xffff))"
> }
> ```

Source: [Sleep_Walker's blog](http://sleepwalker-hnd.blogspot.com/2016/07/tmux-layout-checksum.html).

---

#### Usage

Let's assume you named the script `tmux-grid`. The usage is:

```
tmux-grid columns [rows [target]]
```

`target` is exactly what `tmux … -t` expects. With it you can target any tmux window. If omitted or empty, `$TMUX_PANE` will be used. This way you don't need `target` to change the layout of the current window from within the window itself.

`rows` is the desired number of rows. If omitted or empty, the script will try to calculate this number from the number of existing panes and specified `columns`.

`columns` is the desired number of columns. If empty, the script will try to calculate this number from the number of existing panes and specified `rows`.

In your case invoke one of these from within one of the 6 panes in question:

```
tmux-grid 3      # exactly 3 columns
tmux-grid '' 2   # exactly 2 rows
tmux-grid 3 2    # exactly 3 columns and exactly 2 rows
```

Note in general `tmux-grid 2` needs an even number of panes; `tmux-grid 3` needs the number to be divisible by 3; `tmux-grid 3 2` needs exactly 6 panes.

If each pane is busy, you can invoke the command from another window. In this case you need to specify `target`. This may be handy:

```
tmux-grid 3 '' {marked}
```

<sup>(For users not familiar with the concept of marked pane: [this another answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1521365/432690).)</sup>

---

#### How it works

The script builds a layout of panes of the size 1x1 each. Thanks to the fact `tmux select-layout` recalculates the layout to match the window size, the panes are resized automatically.

<sup>Note: my later tests succeeded with panes of the size 0x0. I kept the original script though.</sup>